# Playstation 4 compatibilities with VR headsets

Tags: ps4, oculus-rift, vive

I am considering getting a VR headset. I am also considering finally getting the PS4.

I won't be choosing the headset merely for whether it's compatible with PS4; There are other uses that are more important to me, for reasons which I can not get the PS VR

I guess the choice, then, is between Oculus Rift and HTC Vive. So the questions become:

1. Which of these are compatible with PS4 games
2. Is there such a thing as "PS4 games compatibility" or is it an individual matter?
3. Are there other VR headset alternatives?

Sorry if the questions seem ignorant; I don't know much about the world of VR.

Answer (score 2):

The only headset compatible with PS4 is PSVR. None of the other VR headsets will work at all with PS4.

Answer (score 0):

No, only the Playstation VR Hardware can be used on the PS4.

[Is it possible to connect the Vive to my PS4? - Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Vive/comments/7ca7cg/is_it_possible_to_connect_the_vive_to_my_ps4/)

> Nope

[Is there anyway to make my Oculus Rift work with my PS4? - Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/oculus/comments/5kfxn2/is_there_anyway_to_make_my_oculus_rift_work_with/)

> There is not no. Only thing that supports the PS4 is the PSVR hmd.
>
> The Rift will only work with a Windows PC, running the correct runtime

.

> Try to understand that it's not just another video display. To handle all of the proper tracking mechanics that the Rift hardware uses, it requires special runtime drivers. The PS4 simply doesn't have any of that software.

ofcause, it might be possible to get them to work by hacking your PS4 if a way has been found, However even then Sony officially supports it's own VR Headset as such you can get support from Sony and a reasonable guarantee that any PS4 VR Game is going to work with the Playstation VR Hardware

Comment: I don't think it would be possible to hack the PS4 to run Oculus/Vive, because PSVR comes with an extra box that does all the VR processing and the console only has to take inputs from it and process the game itself. PS4 just doesn't have the processing power to process VR by itself.

Comment: @Chippies i see, i saw the Playstation VR as an add-on similar to the Playstation Movie and EyeToy

Comment: Playstation VR is an add-on, but it also has a box that goes between the PS4 and the headset, which does most of the processing.